# Derivative of a scalar variable in a transpose-inverse setup

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a bit of an unusual setup and would just like to know if the steps I am taking make sense. I have the following matrices, $A$ is an invertible $p \times p$ matrix, $B$ is a $p \times 1$ matrix or vector whichever wording you prefer, $D$ is a block-diagonal $p \times p$ matrix and not necessarily invertible, $\lambda$ is a constant/scalar, and $\sigma^2$ is the scalar of interest. With these parameters, I have the following defined function,

$$Q=[(A+\frac{\lambda}{\sigma^2}D)^{-1}B]^T$$
Where $T$ stands for the transpose. I now wish to take the derivative of this function with respect to $\sigma^2$. So I would just like to know since the $\sigma^2$ is not a matrix but a scalar what would be the next step I would take and does the transpose play a role in this at all?

$$\frac{dQ}{d \sigma^2}=\frac{d}{d \sigma^2}[(A+\frac{\lambda}{\sigma^2}D)^{-1}B]^T$$

Thank you

Comment: If, for some matrix-valued function $F,\,$ you know that the derivative (wrt $\sigma^2$) is $\dot F=G$ then you also know that $\dot F^T=G^T\;$

Comment: Thanks for the response Greg, does that mean I can rewrite the derivate directly inside of the transpose as $[\frac{d}{d\sigma^2}(A+ \frac{\lambda}{\sigma^2}D)^{-1}B]^T$ and then use the chain rule of matricies to solve this?

Comment: Yes, and remember that the derivative of a matrix inverse is $$\def\s{\sigma^2}\def\M{M^{-1}} \frac{d\M}{d\s}=-\M\left(\frac{dM}{d\s}\right)\M$$